# Creating a common slot for multiple instances of QDoubleSpinBox

Tags: c++, qt, slot, qdoublespinbox

I am trying to create a custom slot that can receive an int and pass it as a double to `QDoubleSpinBox.SetValue(double);`
But I have a bunch of spinboxes in my UI so I would like to have a single slot that can have a DoubleSpinBox pointer as a parameter like so:

```
void MainWindow::ConvertSetSpinBoxValue(int value, QDoubleSpinBox * spinbox)
{
    double ValToDouble = value;
    spinbox->setValue(ValToDouble);
}
```

and then I can connect a widget that emits a Int returning signal i.e. a QSlider:

```
connect(ui->horizontalSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(ConvertSetSpinBoxValue(int, ui->doubleSpinBox)));
```

This connect could be repeated and I would simply change the spinbox pointer. But this doesn't work and the connect is discarded at compilation.
Any idea? thanks!

Comment: Please always include the exact error message in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others pointed out using the (new) Qt5 signals and slots (using function pointers and lambda functions) should solve your problem.

Different methods exist:

1. Using lambda function:

   ```
   connect(ui->horizontalSlider, &QSlider::valueChanged, this /*context*/, [this] (int value) {ui->doubleSpinBox->setValue(value);});
   ```

   Note that the [context](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-5) is useful as it automatically destructs the connection when the context is destructed, but it is probably not needed here as the `ui->horizontalSlider` will probably destructed first.
2. Using `std::bind`:

   ```
   connect(ui->horizontalSlider, &QSlider::valueChanged, this /*context*/, std::bind(&MainWindow::ConvertSetSpinBoxValue, this, value, ui->doubleSpinBox));
   ```
3. **Using implicit conversion between signals/slots:**

   ```
   connect(ui->horizontalSlider, &QSlider::valueChanged, ui->doubleSpinBox, &QDoubleSpinBox::SetValue);
   ```

   Note that the new signal and slot mechanism allows implicit conversion between the signals and slots.

**References**

- [Differences between String-Based and Functor-Based Connections](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html)

Answer (score 2):

Using the new Qt5 signal/slot syntax allows you to connect to a lambda that can capture the `QDoubleSpinBox *` (untested)...

```
auto *sb = ui->doubleSpinBox;
connect(ui->horizontalSlider, &QAbstractSlider::valueChanged, this,
        [this, sb](int value)
        {
            this->ConvertSetSpinBoxValue(value, sb);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
connect(ui->horizontalSlider, &QSlider::valueChanged, 
[this] (int value) { 
    ConvertSetSpinBoxValue(value, ui->doubleSpinBox); 
});
```

1. Please use modern syntax for connections
2. A lambda should help you